# What does it means to find an solution for an elliptical equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations, analytic-geometry

What does it means to find integer solutions for 
$(x-2y)^2+2(y-6)^2=102$ , for example.

Comment: it means you find a solution, $x$ and $y$ so that when you plug them into the equation and evaluate you get  that the equality indeed holds, and it also means that $x$ and $y$ must be integer numbers, not just any reals.

Comment: So, it is just a way to say that some (x,y) pairs that make left side equals to 102 are valid numbers for something else.

Comment: yes valid, being integers